# PHP generate a multidimensional array from mysql two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two tables, `matieres` and `sous_matieres`

`matieres` has `id`, `url` and `title`

`sous_matieres` has `id`, `parent`, `url`, `title`

`url` is the lowercase version of the `title`

`parent` must be the same as `url` of column of `matieres` table so the two tables are joined by `url` of `matieres` and `parent` of `sous_matieres`

How to write a **mySQLi** query using **JOINS** to get a two-dimensional array

Now I have to create panels (divs where the `matiere` as the title and the `sous_matieres` as labels inside the panel) from `matieres` and put `sous_matieres` inside appropriate panels.

Now the best option is to execute one or two queries and create a two-dimensional array and then do the foreach loop on the array.

What the SQl query for that would look like? And how to generate the array out of it?

Comment: Do you know about SQL joins?

Comment: No, absolutely nothing about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) `matieres` to `sous_matieres` in your query.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT 
                        m.id AS m_id, m.url AS m_url, m.title AS m_title, 
                        s.id AS s_id, s.url AS s_url, s.title AS s_title
                     FROM matieres m
                     INNER JOIN sous_matieres s ON m.url = s.parent');
```

Note that using `INNER JOIN` means that you will not get matieres without associated sous_matieres or vice versa. If there are any of those you want to see, you will need to use an outer join instead.

Then, as you fetch rows from the query result, append materials to their related parent keys like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['url'] = $row->m_url;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['title'] = $row->m_title;
    $matieres[$row->m_id]['sous_matieres'][$row->s_id] = $row;
}
```

You should be able to  loop over the resulting array to generate the output you want like this (not exactly the HTML you want, but should be enough to demonstrate the idea):

```
foreach ($matieres as $m_id => $matiere) {
    echo "<h2>$matiere[title]</h2>";
    foreach ($matiere['sous_matieres'] as $id => $sm) {
        echo "<div>
                  <a href='{$sm->s_url}'>{$sm->s_title}</a>
              </div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really what I'm looking for but the problem here is that I'm stuck on translating the SQL query to the actual tables, as what I posted is just a simplified example. Can I edit my original post and you just rewrite the SQL query for me? Thanks.

Comment: I may be able to help. If you update the question I can give it a try, anyway.

Comment: Ok, please wait I will ask it differently and post the link here.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709424/php-generate-a-multidimensional-array-from-mysqli-two-tables-joins

Comment: @medk edited to match your new table info. Hopefully it still makes sense.

Comment: Great, but this shows nothing despite the tables have data. I think the problem is in the mySQLi $stmt->fetch() or something similar as I have changed the $stmt->fetchObject() to $stmt->fetch() and still showing nothing.

Comment: The code in this answer uses pdo rather than mysqli. It should work with mysqli as well, if you use `$stmt->fetch_object()`